# How can I make sure every time the light value goes above 20 the buzzer beeps

Tags: python

I want my buzzer to beep after about 30sec after the light value of my LDR goes above 20

I've tried a while True loop with if statements, Now i'm trying to say while the light <= 20 beep and if light < 20 go back to the beginning but this doesn't work either. I'm sure the value's of my LDR are good

```
light =ADCSPI(10**5)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
buzzer = 27
GPIO.setup(buzzer, GPIO.OUT)

def open_detection():
    print(light.return_light())
    time.sleep(30)
    while light.return_light() >= 20:
        print(light.return_light())
        GPIO.output(buzzer, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(buzzer, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(2)
        if light.return_light() < 20:
            print(light.return_light())
            open_detection()
```

I want the buzzer to beep when the light value is more than 30 seconds above 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor into a loop and keep track of the time your light level has been high enough:

```
light_over_20_time = 0
while True:
    light_level = light.return_light()
    if light_level >= 20:
        light_over_20_time += 1
    else:
        light_over_20_time = 0  # reset counter, too dark

    if light_over_20_time >= 30:
        GPIO.output(buzzer, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        GPIO.output(buzzer, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(2)
        light_over_20_time = 0  # reset counter
    time.sleep(1)
```

This will buzz at every 30 seconds the light level is high enough.
If you want repeat buzzes, remove the second reset.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for a method like this to do it. This is much better my code was a bit buggy